# Creating New Participants Under the Same REDCap Record; Generating Additional Identifier IDs for Records

Tags: database, redcap

I am working on a research project with a goal of identifying individual and household-level risk factors for positive SARS-CoV2 antibody status among residents. Our research team is administering a household survey to participating households that a designated household member would complete, and adult and child surveys that identified household members would complete as well.

Can REDCap generate additional participants under the same record (eg. parent-child cases) and generate unique identifiers/variable IDs for each of the additional participants/household members? Is there a way to create unique variable IDs that we can track on REDCap (ensuring that each of the household members are completing their surveys and knowing which specific member did not complete their survey)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is doable, and I think the best way to achieve it would be to use a different event for each household member.

I am imagining one person from the household (or the project team) would fill out a survey/form where they first responded with how many people in the household (integer, maybe max = 10?), and then depending on the number, display questions pertaining to member_1, member_2, up to member_10, for their name, DOB, gender, etc. (field embedding, in version 10, would certainly help here).

One of the fields could be a hidden ID field which you could use to set a unique ID within the household which, in combination with the record_id (which pertains to the household in total) you could interpolate a unique individual ID like 1-1, 1-2, 1-3. Events could correspond to [member_id] = 1, = 2, etc., and you could pipe the household members demographic info into those events if needed. You could send surveys to household members through alerts and notifications, using the email address entered by the first household member.

In sum, I think it's possible but would take considerable setup, and the setup would multiply in complexity if this were to be actually longitudinal.